# How to use a promise from an jQuery ajax call in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax, promise

I am trying to use promise as follows...

```
 $q.when().then(function () {
    return $rootScope.$emit('resetView', false, 'default');
}).then(function (result) {
    $log.info('login id loaded');   //execute this one first
    checkUserlogin();
}).then(function (result) {
    $log.info('Layout loaded');     //execute this one only when 1st is success. If 1st is failed, dont execute this one.
    loadData();
}, function (error) {
    $log.error("Caught an error:", error);
    return $q.reject('New error');
});
```

As you can see, i have 2 functions to be executed. checkUserLogin() and loadData().

In checkUserLogin(), we check if user is allowed access. User ID is taken and passed to backend via ajax. Database is checked. If access is there, then loadData() should execute. If access is not there, loadData() should not execute.

Currently, this is wat is happening. 
checkUserLogin() is executed. User id is passed to backend via ajax. And directly loadData() gets executed. Now once page is loaded, ajax returns call and gets to know that user doesnot have access. He is redirected to access denied page.

I dont want this to take place. Page loading should only happen once it is confirmed that user has access. Any idea how to achieve this ?

EDIT (As per Paulpro's answer below)

```
$q.when().then(function () {
return $rootScope.$emit('resetView', false, 'default');

}).then(function (result) {
$log.info('checkuser loaded');   //execute this one first
return checkUserlogin();

}).then(function (result) {
$log.info('Layout loaded');     //execute this one only when 1st is success. If 1st is failed, dont execute this one.
return loadData();

}, function (error) {
$log.error("Caught an error:", error);
return $q.reject('New error');
});


var checkUserlogin = function() {
$log.info(' Inside Login check function executed');  
 var serviceURL_CheckUserExists = '/api//CheckUserExists';

    //ajax to check if user exists in database. give/ deny access based on user present in DB and if user is set as blockuser in db. 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceURL_CheckUserExists,
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.Results.length == 1 && response.Results[0].BlockUser == false) {
            $rootScope.myLayout.eventHub.emit('getUserName', response.Results[0].User_ID.trim());

            });
        }
        else { $window.location.href = '../../../BlockUser.html'; }
}
```

as per the above edit- here is the steps which is currently getting executed. $log.info gives output as follows.

```
checkuser loaded
Layout loaded
Inside Login check function executed
```

In actual, these should be the steps.

```
checkuser loaded
Inside Login check function executed
Layout loaded
```

Comment: Can you paste an outline of the code for `checkUserlogin` its important to know what and when it returns. As the answers below state it assumed its a new promise but its not possible to know from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your check function to return a promise and throw if you arn't logged in and return user if you are.

```
var checkUserlogin = function() {
 $log.info(' Inside Login check function executed');  
 var serviceURL_CheckUserExists = '/api/CheckUserExists';

    //ajax to check if user exists in database. give/ deny access based on user present in DB and if user is set as blockuser in db. 
 return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: serviceURL_CheckUserExists,
 }).then(function (response) {
   if (response.Results.length == 1 && response.Results[0].BlockUser == false) {
     return response.Results[0].User_ID.trim();
   }
   else 
   { 
     return null; // could not login
   }
 });
}
```

At which point you can do

```
$q.when().then(function () {
    return $rootScope.$emit('resetView', false, 'default');
}).then(function (result) {
    $log.info('login id loaded');   //execute this one first
    return checkUserlogin();
}).then(function (result) {
    $log.info('Layout loaded');     // execute this when we know if we are logged in or not
   // not logged in
   if (result === null) {
      $window.location.href = '../../../BlockUser.html';
      return;
    }

    // we have a good user so emit
    $rootScope.myLayout.eventHub.emit('getUserName', result);
    // finally load data
    loadData();
}, function (error) { // redirect on blocked user
    $log.error("Caught an error:", error);
});
```

Comment: hi, it gives an error. uncaught could not login at the console.

Comment: this answer is almost there. but it gives error at the last stage. uncaught 'could not login' at the console. Any inputs victory ?

Comment: When access is denied, function(error) should execute and it should direct to BlockUser.html page.  checkUserlogin  function above given by you throws an error stating uncaught could not login if i see the console logs

Comment: I updated it return null if not logged in so we can check for that. Now only errors will call the rejected state on the final promise.

Answer (score 2):

The functions you pass into then should return another Promise, otherwise the call to `then` will return a promise that resolves immediately (to the return value of the function, `undefined` in your case). You want to return promises that don't resolve until the ajax calls are finished. Assuming that `checkUserLogin();` and `loadData();` both return promises, you just need to add a couple of return statements:

```
$q.when().then(function () {
    return $rootScope.$emit('resetView', false, 'default');
}).then(function (result) {
    $log.info('login id loaded');   //execute this one first
    return checkUserlogin();
}).then(function (result) {
    $log.info('Layout loaded');     //execute this one only when 1st is success. If 1st is failed, dont execute this one.
    return loadData();
}, function (error) {
    $log.error("Caught an error:", error);
    return $q.reject('New error');
});
```

If they don't return promises, modify them so that they do (but avoid using the Promise constructor) and then the code above will work.

Comment: also the checkUserLogin promise should be rejected if check fails.

Comment: I have edited the post with your answer. can you please have a look and tell me whats wrong

Comment: @Patrick You need to modify your `checkUserlogin` so that it returns a Promise which should be resolved when the check is complete and successful and rejected if the check fails.

Comment: i didnot get by the term it returns a promise. can you please show an example in checkUserlogin function?

Comment: I added the checkUserlogin function code. Can you please show me there how to return a promise which is resolved when check is complete and successful and reject it when check fails

Comment: @Patrick I believe `$.ajax` returns a promise, especially since you have a call to `.then` on the value it returns. Just adding return in front like `return $.ajax(...` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `checkUserlogin` returns a promise, try...

```
$q.when().then(function() {
    return $rootScope.$emit('resetView', false, 'default');
}).then(function(result) {
    $log.info('login id loaded'); //execute this one first
    checkUserlogin().then(function(result) {
        $log.info('Layout loaded'); //execute this one only when 1st is success. If 1st is failed, dont execute this one.
        loadData();
    }, function(error) {
        $log.error("Caught an error:", error);
        return $q.reject('New error');
    });
});
```